# In App Purchase Download is not happening

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I got a download from Apple server hosted content to work, but in further development of my IAP UI, I've come across a situation where I need to redownload the content.

The content in this case is a zip file, which was created in Xcode as a bundle of images and a plist file containing associated data.

The original download worked fine, and I was able to process the zip file as if it were a directory.

In continuing to develop the app, I deleted the app from my test device. That meant the content was no longer on the device. The in app transaction was never completed, so I expected the download to process again.

Originally, the zip file got downloaded and saved to the caches directory, and I was able to process it from there. Now, though, it seems like the IAP framework thinks the zip file is there but it really isn't. The `paymentQueue:updatedDownloads:` method is triggered with download state equal to `SKDownloadStateFinished` without any download activity happening. OK. That's not in my control. I need to just look at the URL of the download I was given, right? So, within `case SKDownloadStateFinished:` I have a call to `[self processURL:download.contentURL fromProduct:download.contentIdentifier];`, which processes the referenced download. Here is the start of that method:

```
-(void)processURL:(NSURL *)directoryURL fromProduct:(NSString *)productIdentifier
{
   int itemsAdded = 0;
   NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
   NSMutableSet *masterIndex = [NSMutableSet new];
   BOOL isDir;
   if ([filemanager fileExistsAtPath:[directoryURL path] isDirectory:&isDir]) {
      NSLog(@"URL %@ exists. Is it a directory? %@",directoryURL,isDir?@"YES":@"NO");
   } else {
      NSLog(@"URL %@ does not exist.",directoryURL);
   }
```

What I am getting as output is:

```
URL file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/40733984-E18D-4450-A98E-D8CCC56D2600/Library/Caches/8E29E63C-9C32-4D92-AC84-23BDA946DE5F.zip/ does not exist.
```

A call to `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];` doesn't seem to help. It just thinks it's finished without redownloading the zip file.

Any suggestions on what to do?

EDIT: This is really getting frustrating. Since my original post, I've tried the following:
* Rebooted my iPad
* Restarted Xcode
* Ran a clean on my iPad (I wasn't holding my breath - I was hoping to clear the caches directory, which I think is inaccessible to the cleaning utility)
* Updated my in app purchase package with updated information in the plist file.
* Updated the version of the in app purchase package.

When it tries to download, it is still trying to download the same zip file name, and it still doesn't exist. I thought by changing the package, even with the same package name, the download would pull a different zip name. But maybe it's just a hash or the package name.

I have an idea that the caches directory is corrupted somehow. My next step will be to create another package with a different package name. I'm guessing this will work fine, but that doesn't resolve my problem.

I also have an idea of the circumstances that may have caused the problem. It seems like Xcode 5 is slower to respond to pressing the build and run button. The result was that I clicked it twice. Of course, that causes problems. In this case, I got some sort of deadly embrace, I think, that locked up my iPad. I had to manually power it down and restart it twice before it came back again properly.

Edit:
The new items are not downloading. Here's a checklist of items I've checked. Please edit this to include more items to check if you think of more.

- Make sure the test user has not been used in production. If so, a new test user will need to be created.
- Make sure the object registers as an SKPaymentTransactionObserver. This includes setting up the interface, and also making the call `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self]` at startup.
- Make sure user can make payments.
- Make sure `transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` (or `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` if restoring a transaction)
- Make sure the transaction is not finished (`[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction]`).
- Make sure the product ID matches to product ID set up in iTunes Connect (well, you wouldn't have been able to purchase it if this weren't true).
- Test on a physical device. These downloads cannot be tested on the simulator.
- (speculative) turn off notifications for App Store to prevent test user from being nullified.

Comment: Well, now it's working. I didn't really do anything different. However, I did upgrade to iOS 7.0.3 on the off chance that would make a difference. It did not. Then I tried creating yet another test user, and this time it worked. This time when creating a new user I didn't go through all the prompts (like filling in CC information). I canceled that process. I'm guessing the process can be skipped after accepting the agreement.

Comment: I have a theory for why this is happening. I had App Store turned on in the notification center. Perhaps iOS checking for new app versions caused my logged test user to be used in the production environment, thus nullifying my test user. In case that might be what's happening, I went to Settings, Notification Center, and turned off notifications for App Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience with in-app purchase with Apple hosted downloads, if a downloads object is received and the URL given points to a file that does not exist, that transaction is now worthless (probably from a test user being invalidated or deleted). Best thing to do is to finish that transaction, and if you need the download again, ask for a new one via purchase or restore. The new one won't simply be a regurgitated transaction pointing to a deleted file but will be associated with a new set of downloads.